# java Double.valueOf() returns number with one decimal place

Tags: android, number-formatting, decimalformat

I can't seem to get my head around this. If have tried the following approaches:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00000.00");

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("######.##");
```

But the following line always generates and IllegalArgumentException.

```
double price = Double.valueOf(df.format(((EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.edit_item_price)).getText().toString()));
// Sample input passed is value of 200 or some other whole number.
item.setPrice(price);
```

It doesn't make sense as I only copied the obvious solutions in this forum. Most of you got the format() to work.

Originally, I didn't have these lines of code. I just call my setPrice() method after getting the item price. This works. However, Double.valueOf() has a nasty habit of using only one decimal position.

e.g. passed 200. I get 200.0 inside my item object. I figured by using DecimalFormat I could've prevented this but it appears this caused me MORE headaches instead.

Comment: Apparently, this code works as a standalone java app. It only fails when using it with an android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you pass 200 and you get 200.0, you mean you get it in a double value? If so, that doesn't matter - it's a number and 200 = 200.0 for double values.

Comment: Okay, it seems I was making a big fuss over something so pointless. I was catching this data on its way to the database and realized I didn't need to do this. So I just formatted the number as it was being pulled out of the database and being rendered on screen. Your suggestion helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

format(...) turns a double value to a String value. You have it the other way round. That's why you get the Exception.

If the price variable is actually a double you should do

`double price = Double.valueOf(((EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.edit_item_price)).getText().toString())`

But I think you want that the price is a String, then you should convert the text from the EditText to a double and that double back to a String with something like `new DecimalFormat("0.00")`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy my code accurately, I added that missing valueOf(). The main issue there was that format would fail by itself. even if you declare a different variable to hold it.